# Merging changes from one branch to other in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I have some 100 files to be merged from one branch to the other. Here is the set up that I have.

There are two branches Branch A and Branch B. I have to merge elements pointed to by a particular label (say Label X ) on Branch A to Branch B.

What is the fastest way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Merge manager, but I would suggest:

- use a dynamic view as destination for the merge (even if you are usually working with a snapshot view). You will ensure:

  - a quicker merge (no problem of updates)
  - a merge not blocked by files currently checked out in your working view
- set the merge manager with a label (and not just from a branch A, because it would select the LATEST element found in that branch, and not just the ones selected by `LabelX`)
- preview it if you want in command line with the "[`cleartool findmerge`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm)" command.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Merge Manager to select my branch to merge to (in your case branch B), and then select the branch to merge from (branch A). There really is no faster way to do so.

It will find files to be merged, and all of them will be selected by default. You can choose files that should not be merged, if you wish.